# Entity Framework - Saving a snapshot of a document in a SQL database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, refactoring

**Background** I am using EF6 and is free to change the database.

I ran into this problem today. Say I have:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

The users are allowed to update `Company` and `Address`. Users are also allowed to update `Invoice`. But since it is a financial document, it must somehow save a snapshot of the address if the user marks `IsCompleted` to true.

Currently it is done in the following way:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    //Auditing fields 
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
}
```

I think this is hard to follow. I was thinking:

Option 1: Save an audit to an audit table of its own:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    //Null if IsCompleted = false. 
    public DateTime? CompletedTimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyAudit
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class AddressAudit
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

But then that seems like a lot of tables to create and a lot of work if we do change the schema for Company and Address. Also, it's not very robust. I can't reuse this for other documents without a bunch of wiring. However, this is what I found mostly on the internet. One audit table for each table.

Option 2: Save all the audit to the same table:

```
public class Audit
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

But then, this seems like it's not very standard. I have never saved Json data to a SQL database before. Is this bad? If so What could go wrong?

Should I go with Option 1 or Option 2?

Comment: If you don't need to view your audit tables through your application then you could perform this in SQL Server using triggers and separate audit tables. SQL Server also support Change Data Capture (CDC) that you can configure to capture changes to any tables that you want. You could then extract this into your audit table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SteveFord. However we do need to display this data in the application, mainly for generation of some PDF reports and displaying data in a grid. So I think CDC is not a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Assuming you are using SQL Server, I would recommend creating some **XML-serializable DTOs** for that job and **storing XML in a dedicated column**, using the XML datatype.

### Slightly longer answer

I have already gone that exact same path. We needed to save a snapshot of data at the point that it has been printed out, and there were many tables involved that would have been duplicated in the process.

**Requirements and Evaluation**

We didn't want to incorporate an additional technology (e.g. File System as proposed by Andreas or some NoSQL/document database), but store everything in SQL Server, as otherwise this would have complicated backup scenarios, deployment, maintenance and so on.

We wanted something easy to understand. New developers should be familiar with the technology used. Architecture shouldn't be influenced too much.

For serialization, there are several options: [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx), [JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json), [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.110).aspx), [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073(v=vs.110).aspx), [Protocol Buffers.](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).. Our requirements: Easy versioning (for added properties or relationships), readability, conformance with SQL Server.

Easy versioning should be possible using all mentioned formats. Readability: XML and JSON win here. Conformance with SQL Server: [XML is supported in SQL Server natively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb522493(v=sql.100).aspx) and was our choice.

**Implementation**

We did several things:

1. **Create additional DTOs** in our database project, side by side with the existing Entities, not for usage with EF but for XML serialization. They are annotated with XmlAttributes and resemble a complex, self-contained structure with everything that is needed to hold the document's data. The root `InvoiceSnapshot` class has `Parse` and `ToXml` methods to support serialization.
2. **Update our Entities** to include the snapshots, where required:

   ```
   public string InvoiceXml { get; set; }

   public InvoiceSnapshot Invoice
   {
       get 
       { 
           return this.InvoiceXml != null 
               ? InvoiceSnapshot.Parse(this.InvoiceXml)
               : null; 
       }
       set { this.InvoiceXml = value != null ? value.ToXml() : null; }
   }
   ```
3. **Update the [entity configuration](http://www.remondo.net/code-first-fluent-api-entity-type-configuration/)** to create an XML column and ignore the `InvoiceSnapshot` property:

   ```
   public class InvoiceEntityConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<InvoiceEntity>
   {
       public InvoiceEntityConfig()
       {
           this.Property(c => c.InvoiceXml).HasColumnType("xml");
           this.Ignore(c => c.Invoice);
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Modify our business objects** so that they load themselves either from Entities (editable state) or from XML-DTOs (snapshot, readonly state). We use interfaces on both where they help streamlining the process.

**Further steps**

- You should add metadata for common queries in separate scalar columns and index them. Retrieve the xml data only when you really want to show the invoice.
- You can look into [what SQL Server can do for you regarding XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb522493(v=sql.100).aspx), especially when you need to query based on attributes. It can index them, and you can use XPath in queries.
- Sign or hash your xml to make sure that snapshot data won't be tampered with.

Comment: This is exactly what I need @frank. I think it would work well in our application. How would you handle change of schema in your Entity? Say, if you added a new column in Invoice call `ExtraData`, would you go back to the XML and create an empty <ExtraData> section?

Comment: Yes, I would do so. You could have a common interface to enforce this, but there are situations where the data doesn't even have to match. While a phone number could be multiple fields in the editable, relational world, it could come down to a single string in the snapshot. In our case, we had many little differences all over the place, but they made sense as storing a single document is a different paradigm as storing relational data.

Answer (score 0):

Option2

BUT

A better way is to store the genrated invoice (pdf)
and all reversions of it in normal files.

You can still use your Invoice table
but then u dont need to wory if some customer-data change
and an user reprints an older document.

To store the generated documents it's near the same
as to store the model in JsonData but u dont Need to
safe the Version of your template and template generator.

Option1 is just brut force and is maybe better released 
with the "Event Store", "Event Sourcing" and "Query and Command" pattern.

```
public class Document //or DocumentFile
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public String Owner { get; set;} //exp. "Customer:Id", "Contact:Id"  maybe just int
    [Index]
    public String Reference { get; set; } //exp. "Invoice:Id", "Contract:Id"   maybe just int
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } //maybe int Reversion
}
```